# Getting control name for an event

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

In my C# Windows Forms form I have some buttons which are dynamically generated. I assigned the following method on the click event. Is it possible to get the name of the button from which the event is triggered?

```
private void btnBrowsDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            gbxDocument.Controls["txtDocument" + count].Text =
                openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `try...catch`? - This is usually a rather bad programming style, especially if you are not evaluating the caught exception.

Comment: @ Uwe Keim : am handle the exception using a text file... i just remove that line of code while adding here...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `sender` argument. That is the Control (the button in this case) that has raised the click event:

```
var button = (Button)sender;
button.Name ...
```

N.B.: In case you have subscribed other controls (e.g. panels, etc.) to the same event handler, you can check if the sender is a button using the `as`operator:

```
var button = sender as Button;
if (button != null)
{
    button.Name ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the N.B. section, I think it would be better to check with the 'is' parameter and then perform the action. Otherwise you cannot cast the sender again. e.g. if (sender is Button) return (sender as button).Name; else if (sender is Panel) return (sender as Panel).Name; etc.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli : it really depends on what you need. If you just need to check if is a button, I would stick with `as`, but it's a matter of preference

Answer (score 5):

The first argument of the [event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), "`object sender`", contains a reference of an object/control which raised/fired an event.

```
var button = sender as Button;
```