# Get Multiple Panel Name With Same Click Event When Click On It in c#

Tags: c#, events, click, controls, directoryinfo

i have a loop to make multiple panel with this properties:
1.Name
2.Left
3.Top
4.Width
5.Height
6.Backcolor
And an Click Event

my problem is in Click Event
each of this panel that loop was made , have this event .

How can I get the panel name that was created by this loop . When click on it ?

Here is My Code

```
void showPanel()
    {
        VideoList list = new VideoList();
        int left = 125;
        int top = 50;

        DirectoryInfo[] d = new DirectoryInfo("videos").GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in d)
        {
            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            list.panel1.Controls.Add(pnl);
            pnl.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

            if (!File.Exists("videos\\" + dir.Name + "\\image.jpg"))
                pnl.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            else
            {
                pnl.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                pnl.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("videos\\" + dir.Name + "\\image.jpg");
            }

            pnl.Click += new EventHandler(pnl_Click);
            pnl.Name = dir.Name;
            pnl.Left = left;
            pnl.Top = top;
            pnl.Width = 150;
            pnl.Height = 100;
            left += 200;
            if (left >= 750)
            {
                left = 125;
                top += 150;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why My Hello wasn't add the top of my posts?

Comment: WPF, WinForms or WebForms?

Comment: Your `pnl_Click` gets a `sender` parameter. That should point to your panel.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644131/getting-control-name-for-an-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting control name for an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644131/getting-control-name-for-an-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the Event Handler implementation (pnl_Click), it should look something like:

```
private void pnl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

For you, the important part is the `sender` parameter. This always refers to the control that initiated the event, in this case, the Click event.

If you add the line:

```
Panel thisPanel = sender as Panel;
```

at the start of the Event Handler implementation, you will be able to interact with the Panel that raised the event by using, for example, `thisPanel.Name`